# Using continue in try/except statement

Tags: python, pandas, try-catch, continue

I am working with a Pandas dataframe and iterating over the rows to find relevant data, in this case, colors. For the most part, the 'Color' column's cell will be filled out, in which case I do not need to search other cells in the row for colors and can continue to the next row. However, if no 'Color' column is present, Pandas will raise a `KeyError` and I will need to create the column and add values to it. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class Reader(object):

    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        """Grabs column headers, converts dataframe from unicode string objects to 
        Python string objects, sets dataValues class variable equal to a numpy array of the sheet"""
        self.headers = dataframe.columns.values
        self.dataFrame = dataframe.applymap(str)
        self.dataValues = self.dataFrame[:].values


class Extractor(object):
"""Extracts relevant spec information from a sku (row)"""

    def getColor(self, colorRef):
        """Looks in Model Name and Description for color information. 
        Uses pre-existing color database (colorRef).
        Returns dataFrame column 'Color' """
        index = 0
        newColorArray = [] #this will not be returned, its sole purpose is to keep track of colors
        for sku in myData.dataValues:
            try:
                if myData.dataFrame.iloc[index, myData.dataFrame.columns.get_loc('Color') != ('' or ' '):
                    continue #color exists, move to next row
            except KeyError:
                newColorArray = ['']*myData.dataFrame.shape[0]
            #Remaining code searches for colors
```

When I try to execute that block of code, I get a `SyntaxError`. I have read  e-satis's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/9743339) but, if I understand `yield` correctly, this will terminate the function and not this iteration of the loop. Is what I am trying to do even possible in Python?

I do not have a lot of practice using objects and classes, so if you'd like to give me feedback there as well, please do.

Comment: Seems to be the line after ````try:````. You are missing a ````]```` for ````iloc````. Then you probably need ````in ['', ' ']```` as opposed to ````!= ('' or ' ')````

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I feel dumb. Thank you.